# Странности при удалении строки из таблицы

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Пытаюсь удалить строку из таблицы. Строка раскрывающаяся и содержит кнопки, одна из которых "Удалить".
При нажатии на кнопку срабатывает(описан в 'cellForRowAtIndexPath'):

```
[cell.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteOrder:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Который запускает метод 'deleteOrder':

```
-(void)deleteOrder:(UIButton *) sender {
/* тут http-запрос для удаления записи с сервера */    
        [messages removeObjectAtIndex:selectedRow]; // удаление элемента с таблицы. NSMutableArray.
        [tView reloadData]; // перезагрузка TbaleView.
}
```

selectedRow - это номер строки. Записывается в 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath', как:

```
selectedRow = indexPath.row;
```

Проблема в том, что при удалении строки она удаляется и появляется на месте первого элемента в таблице. При перезагрузке вьюшки, запись исчезает, т.к. данные берутся с сервера.

Также пробовал и через:

```
    [tView beginUpdates];
    [tView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tView endUpdates];
```

Итог такой же. Удаленная строка появляется на первом месте.

Схема работы вьюшки такая: при загрузке, в 'viewDidLoad' выполняется http-запрос на сервер и получаются данные, которые записываются в массив и выводятся в виде таблицы.

Comment: Вопрос еще актуален:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что происходит в методе ?
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

он должен возвращать обновленный (после удаления) список messages

Comment: там прописано только: return [messages count];
И в дебаг моде смотрел: строка точно удаляется из messages, но непонятно каким образом появляется в TableView.